# --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters controller: welcome action: index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, actioncontroller

I looked all over the internet before asking this, I don't know what I did wrong but now that I refresh my index page, this code is showing in the main page:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters 
controller: welcome 
action: index
```

How do I get it out of there? Does somebody have deal with this before?

An example of this I found it on this guys unfinished webpage:

[Example at the bottom of the webpage](https://www.compwiz.info/)

That Is all that I could found on the entire internet about this..

Comment: seems that the request parameters just rendered like `render params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `debug(...)` from your controller action. You are seeing this because your `index` controller action is calling `ActionView::Helpers::DebugHelper`. More info on DebugHelper [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, you are totally correct and everything is flowing as it should be now!